# R has reached total allocation while inputting data

Tags: r, memory

I am having an issue with inputting a (somewhat) large dataset into R. It is about 3.5 GB.

1. Ideally, I would like to use `read_sas` in the "haven" package, but it's producing issues bc the file is compressed.
2. I am using the `read.sas7bdat` function - when I try to input my dataset, it gives the following message:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 30.4 Mb In addition: Warning
>   messages:   Reached total allocation of 8149Mb: see help(memory.size)

It says the vector is of size 30.4 Mb. I have checked the `memory.limit()` and it is 8149. This is much larger than the size of my dataset. I've changed the size of my memory limit to 20000 (`memory.limit(size=20000)`) and it's running and crashing. The OS is 64-bit and I've made sure R-version is also 64-bit.

I've read through all the forums on this, and still can't seem to figure out why this happening/how I can fix it. Right now, cutting down the size isn't really an option, plus it's not that big of a data set relatively.

Comment: 3.5G is "not that big" ...?  Does 3.5G refer to the size of the data set on disk? Compressed, uncompressed (I don't know whether SAS data sets are compressed by default/compressible or not)?  How much total memory does the machine have?

Comment: When the error says "cannot allocate vector of size 30.4 Mb," it means that there is less the 30.4Mb of useful memory available.

Comment: It refers to the compressed size of data on disk. The machine has a total of 8.00 GB of installed memory.

Comment: Go to AWS. Start a virtual machine. Set your RAM to a large number. Play.